# Removing microphone indicator in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am currently working with webRTC and therefore use the getUserMedia() function. When doing this a red icon appears inside the tab-header. Is there a way to remove this symbol? I set my microphone stream to undefined after a certain task, but the symbol is still shown there.

Comment: Are you accessing the microphone at all?

Comment: Yes, for a short time

Comment: I don't think you can then, once you've asked for permission to use it...

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/44274410/1066234

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to stop the `MediaStream` (`MediaStreamTracks`) you've acquired with `getUserMedia`

```
stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
stream.stop(); // deprecated in FFox
```

Comment: Thanks for that :) Is there a way to start the track afterwards again?

Comment: Nope, you'd need to acquire a new stream. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack

Comment: What if stream was started by third party and i did not call getUserMedia to initilize the stream then in this case how do i get the reference of created stream object and how to stop it?

Comment: That really depends on the third party library and how they manage the stream object. If it is open source I'd suggest looking into the source code, otherwise their documentation.  Or you can try and get some information about the environment through the browser's debugger.